# Transpose one row into multiple rows based on a cell value in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Sorry for the previous question, it was unclear. I have edited it.

I have a MySql View that has 3 columns i.e. Schoolcode, No, and Gender. Below is the structure of the table

| Code| No |Gender|
+----------------------

|  SLX | 12  |  Female    |

I want to transpose the above one row into 12 rows based on the value 12 in column "No" . I would like to repeat the code SLX 12 times and the gender "Female" 12 times
How do I do this in Mysql?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: Please edit the question and attach things like

Back end code, the language you're using, how are you iterating the mysql rows.

This question is really hard to understand, some would not even consider it as a question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table that will hold X numbers (X=the max of your column 'No')

```
+---+
| n |
+---+
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
|   |
| X |
+---+
```

Your query is then

```
select code,gender
from
  yourTable t
  join numbers nb on nb.n<=t.no
```